# Passing FirestoreListView query data to SfCartesianChart

Tags: flutter, google-cloud-firestore, syncfusion

Have a FirestoreListView that query data and show a list, also have SfCartesianChart in a floating button under the body of the FirestoreListView, can't pass the data and I would rater not do another query when I already have the data in the format I want.

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
return Scaffold(
  appBar: MyAppBar(title: 'Estadisticas de uso'),
  bottomNavigationBar: const MyNavBar(screen: routeName),
  body: FirestoreListView(
    pageSize: 20,
    query: FirebaseFirestore.instance
        .collection('uso')
        //.where('usoEdtEstAsigId', isEqualTo: user!.uid)
        .orderBy('usoOn', descending: true),
    loadingBuilder: (_) => Column(
      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
      children: [
        Row(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
          children: [
            CircularProgressIndicator(),
          ],
        ),
      ],
    ),
    itemBuilder: ((context, snapshot) {
      Map<String, dynamic> data = snapshot.data();
      Timestamp tOn = data['usoOn'] as Timestamp;
      DateTime dateOn = tOn.toDate();
      Timestamp tOff = data['usoOff'] as Timestamp;
      DateTime dateOff = tOff.toDate();

      //Place 1, check in the end for info
      /*dynamic getColumnData(){
        List<StaticData> columnData = <StaticData>[
        StaticData(dateOn, data['usoMinutos'])
       ];
       return columnData;
      }*/
      return SingleChildScrollView(
   }),
 ),
```

The floating button, outside the body: FireStoreListView, so it can remain while scrolling the page.

```
floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton.extended(
    onPressed: () {
      showModalBottomSheet<void>(
          context: context,
          builder: ((BuildContext context) {
            return Container(
              height: 400,
              margin: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 5, left: 10, right: 10),
              child: Center(
                child: Column(
                    mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
                    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                    children: <Widget>[
                      Row(
                        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                        children: [
                          SfCartesianChart(
                              primaryXAxis: DateTimeAxis(
                                  title: AxisTitle(text: 'Fecha y hora')),
                              primaryYAxis: NumericAxis(
                                  title: AxisTitle(text: 'Minutos')),
                              title: ChartTitle(
                                  text:
                                      'Grafico de Minutos de Uso / Tiempo de Encendido',
                                  textStyle: TextStyle(
                                      fontSize: 12,
                                      fontWeight: FontWeight.bold)),
                              //legend: Legend(isVisible: true),
                              tooltipBehavior:
                                  TooltipBehavior(enable: true),
                              series: <ChartSeries>[
                                ColumnSeries<StaticData, DateTime>(
                                    dataSource: getColumnData(),
                                    xValueMapper: (StaticData static, _) =>
                                        static.x,
                                    yValueMapper: (StaticData static, _) =>
                                        static.y,
                                    dataLabelSettings: DataLabelSettings(
                                      isVisible: true,
                                    ))
                              ]),
                        ],
                      ),
```

Also setting the graph

```
class StaticData {
   DateTime x;
   double y;
StaticData(this.x, this.y);
}
```

But this is the problem, this is how I use the data and set it for the columns, if I add it outside I can't access the data but the method is called, but I also need the data from the query and the transformation of the date from Timestamp. If I add it in the itemBuilder under the transformation, I can't access the method from the Graph because it's under the body.

Place 2: outside the main class

```
dynamic getColumnData(){
  List<StaticData> columnData = <StaticData>[
      StaticData(dateOn, data['usoMinutos'])
    ];
    return columnData;
}
```

Any help is welcome, also would like to know if the graph will actually work like that. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

We already have a KB for fetching the data from the Firestore database and mapping it to the CartesianChart series. We have shared the Firestore-related KB link below for your reference.

KB,

https://www.syncfusion.com/kb/13022/how-to-render-the-flutter-chart-using-the-data-in-firestore-sfcartesianchart

Comment: Thanks for the reply but that is not related to this case, I am trying to pass the data from the FirestoreListView query into the syncfusion chart, if I use that example I will have 2 queries for every pageview when I already have the data to view. The page already shows the data, I am just adding a button with a ModalBottomSheet and a chart in it.